# Conditional formatting no working with downloaded data

Tags: excel

I downloaded data from our internal system and tried to apply conditional formatting, but it is not working. I cleared all the rules from the sheet and changed the format to Number, and everything is unsuccessful. However, if I replace the data manually it is working. I have huge numbers of rows and cannot change and edit them manually. Is there a workaround for this? I wanted to attach test data, but I don't find a way to attach to this post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The numbers are probably coming in as strings, which cannot be formatted. Try saving it as a CSV and then close it and open the CSV.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!! But, I formatted the cells as Number, how can it save it as a string?

Comment: It doesnt work the way you think it does. Number formatting only works if it's an actual number, it doesnt convert the string formatted number to an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are probably coming in as strings, which cannot be formatted. Try saving it as a CSV and then close it and open the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Characters taken from other sources may have spaces. The Code function results in the numeric code of the characters in the cells-Look for the cells in which the spaces are spaces with the code number 32. It is often the case that there is a space between the code number 160.
Use function =trim(Cell or Range)  or check if You have this white marks" hard space" 160 or 32 in cells you downloaded data.

Check =Code(Cell) what nr code You have in cells if any or copy space and insert between quotation marks. =CODE(" ").Invisible space charts may not allow formatting cells with other sources.